# NodeJS | Passing an object as function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've had a small problem I couldn't overcome this week, I'm trying to pass a JSON object as a parameter in a function but it always tells me that I can't do that, but I don't want to end up sending the 50 values separately from my json object.

Here is the set up on my app, this is working as intended with express :

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

Here is the routing index from the previous line of code (Note that I'm using jade for rendering and I'm using the next function to pass parameters to it like the name in this one :

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  getprofile.profileFunc(function(result) {
    res.render('index', { name: result });  
  });
};
```

Next it calls the function profileFunc from getprofile :

```
var profileFunc = function(callback) {
var sapi = require('sapi')('rest');

  sapi.userprofile('name_here', function(error, profile) {
    var result = [profile.data.name];
    callback.apply(null, result);
  });

};
exports.profileFunc = profileFunc;
```

Note that I was only able to pass a string result and have it displayed in the jade render, what I want to do is pass the profile object to use it in the render to display name, age, birthday but I can't get it to work, it will either pass a undefined object or not pass.

Thanks for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest the following:

```
var profileFunc = function(callback) {
    var sapi = require('sapi')('rest');
    sapi.userprofile('name_here', function(error, profile) {
        callback.apply(null, profile);
    });
};
exports.profileFunc = profileFunc;

...

getprofile.profileFunc(function(result) {
    res.render('index', result);  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that, but when I used #{result.data.name} in my jade file it returned me an error : "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Comment: Did you try with just *data.name*?

Comment: Yes, I tried with data.name but it sent me the same error. Looks like my json object was not send to it.

Comment: I'll suggest to put console.log before res.render and see what exactly is in *result*.

Comment: I used console.log before the render but it's undefined so the problem is "passing" the object from the function who gets it. I tried to log what "profile" is before I use callback.apply and it's ok, so my problem must be the way I do my callback or call function?

Answer (score 0):

If you put an `Object` into Jade's template context, then you'll have to reference it using the variable containing that `Object`. In your templates, you'd access that using `name.foo`, `name.bar`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is with apply, apply takes array as second argument so when you are trying to send object its not working. Just use callback function without apply like this:-

```
var profileFunc = function(callback) {
    var sapi = require('sapi')('rest');
    sapi.userprofile('name_here', function(error, profile) {
        callback(profile);
    });
};
exports.profileFunc = profileFunc;

...

getprofile.profileFunc(function(result) {
    res.render('index', result);  
});
```